# Plus Primes vs Minus Primes

Tags: code-golf, primes, counting

## Most of us know...

that all primes `p>3` are of the form    [image]

But, how many are the **Plus Primes** (`6n+1`) and how many are the **Minus Primes** (`6n-1`) in a certain range?

## The Challenge

Given an integer `k>5` , count how many `primes<=k` are **PlusPrimes** and how many are **MinusPrimes**.

## Examples

for `k=100` we have
`[5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 41, 47, 53, 59, 71, 83, 89]`  **12 MinusPrimes**
and
`[7, 13, 19, 31, 37, 43, 61, 67, 73, 79, 97]`      **11 PlusPrimes**

for `k=149` we have
`[5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 41, 47, 53, 59, 71, 83, 89, 101, 107, 113, 131, 137, 149]`
**18 MinusPrimes**
and
`[7, 13, 19, 31, 37, 43, 61, 67, 73, 79, 97, 103, 109, 127, 139]`
**15 PlusPrimes**

## Rules

Your code must output **2 integers**: one for the **MinusPrimes** and one for the **PlusPrimes** in any order you like (please specify which is which).
This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Test Cases

> **Input** -> **Output**    [**MinusPrimes**,**PlusPrimes**]

```
6->[1,0]  
7->[1,1]   
86->[11,10]  
986->[86,78]  
5252->[351,344]  
100000->[4806,4784]   
4000000->[141696, 141448]
```

Comment: **I did not know!** :(

Comment: @StewieGriffin, it's easy to intuit if you look at the modulus sequence: `0%6` is a multiple of 6, `1%6` cannot be determined, `2%6` is a multiple of 2, `3%6` is a multiple of 3, `4%6` is a multiple of 2, and `5%6` cannot be determined.

Comment: @zzzzBov that'd be really helpful if I knew why modulus had a sequence, and what it meant for primes... I wish high school taught number theory...

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix, modulus means "remainder after division". 0, 6, 12, etc all produce 0 after division by 6; 1, 7, 13 all produce 1. Since we're looking for numbers that can't be divided into factors, knowing that a number is divisible by an integer greater than 1 tells us that the number is not prime.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*

Outputs as `[PlusPrimes, MinusPrimes]`

```
LDpÏ6%5Ñ¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx6XgcL@ZqunhiYcW/f9vYQYA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvnfx6XgcL@ZqunhiYcW/a9UOrzfSuHwfiWd/2Zc5lwWZlyWQGxqZGrEZWgAAgA)

**Explanation**

```
L             # push range [1 ... input]
 DpÏ          # keep only primes
    6%        # mod each by 6
      5Ñ      # divisors of 5 [1, 5]
        ¢     # count
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 77 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Neil</sup>

```python
lambda x:[sum(all(n%j for j in range(2,n))for n in range(i,x,6))for i in 7,5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKrq4NFcjMSdHI081SyEtv0ghSyEzT6EoMS89VcNIJ09TEySWhxDL1KnQMYOIZoJEzXVMY/8XFGXmlSikaZhpcsGYFkhsS2SOqZGpkeZ/AA)

#### Previous solution, <s>83</s> <s>81</s> 79 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder</sup>
<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Halvard Hummel</sup>

```python
lambda x:map([all(n%i for i in range(2,n))*n%6for n in range(4,x)].count,[5,1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjexQCM6MSdHI081UyEtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNIJ09TUytP1QwknocQN9Gp0IzVS84vzSvRiTbVMYzV/F9QlJlXopCmYabJBWNaILEtkTmmRqZGmv8B)
Both output as [MinusPrimes,PlusPrimes]

Comment: [83](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjexQCNaty5P1Swtv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcNEp0IzM00hMSdHI081UwEkm4mQNdLJ09SM1UvOL80r0Yk20DGK1fxfUJSZV6KQpmGmyQVjWiCxLZE5pkamRpr/AQ)

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjexQCM6T9UsLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXDRKdCMzNNITEnRyNPNVMBJJuJkDXSydPUjNVLzi/NK9GJNtQxjdX8X1CUmVeikKZhpskFY1ogsS2ROaZGpkaa/wE)

Comment: [80?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKrq4NFcjOjEnRyNPNUshLb9IIUshM0@hKDEvPVXDSCdPUxMklocQy9Sp0DHTjAULZwKFo811TGNj/xcUZeaVKKRpmGlywZgWSGxLZI6pkamR5n8A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: I've done too many JavaScript array comprehensions - I'd forgotten that Python lists often don't need `[]`s.

Comment: So, you divide n by all numbers from i to n-1 to see if it is prime, then generate all of the integers (5,11,...) and (7,13, ...) and test if the number in question is there, and count them.  Seems efficient.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk that's why I didn't added the last 2 test cases on the link c:

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
Zq6\!5lh=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6rQLEbRNCfDtvj/fxMDMAAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@q0CxG0TQnw7b4v0vIfzMucy4LMy5LIDY1MjXiMjQAAS4TMGUAAA).

#### Explanation

```
Zq     % Implicitly input k. Push row vector of primes up to k
6\     % Modulo 6, element-wise
!      % Transpose into a column vector
5lh    % Push row vector [5, 1]
=      % Is equal?, element-wise with broadcast
s      % Sum of each column. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

Output order is `[+,-]`.

```
õj ò6 yx ë4
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9Wog8jYgeXgg6zQ=&input=MTQ5Ci1R)

- Took some inspiration from [Dennis' Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140960/58974) but, after golfing, it's closer to being a port.
- 2 bytes saved thank to Oliver bringing the previously-unknown-to-me `ë` method for arrays to my attention.

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
õj
```

Generate an array of integers (`õ`) from 1 to `U` and check if each is a prime (`j`), giving an array of booleans.

```
ò6
```

Partition the array into sub-arrays of length 6.

```
yx
```

Transpose (`y`) and sum the columns.

```
ë4
```

Get every 4th element of the array and implicitly output them.

---

### Original, <s>19</s> <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
õ fj
5â £è_%6¥X
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SBmagpGcyCso+hfJTalWA==&input=MTQ5)

- 1 byte thanks to an inspired suggestion from Oliver to use the divisors of 5 after I'd rested on my laurels splitting 15 to an array.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
(s=#;Mod[Prime~Array~PrimePi@s,6]~Count~#&/@{5,1})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfo9hW2do3PyU6oCgzN7XOsagosbIOzA7IdCjWMYutc84vzSupU1bTd6g21TGs1VT7D5TOK1FwSIs2i@WCs82R2BbIEpYg3v//AA)

@ngenisis golfed it down, saving 4 bytes

## Mathematica, 47 bytes

```
sPrime~Array~PrimePi@s~Mod~6~Count~#&/@{5,1}
```

Comment: `Mod` can also be infix, and if you're going to name the first argument `s`, just use a named argument: `sPrime~Array~PrimePi@s~Mod~6~Count~#&/@{5,1}`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
s6ÆPSm4
```

Plus, then minus.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Y7HBbQHCuyf/D7Y@a1rj//2@mo2Cuo2ABpCxBhKmRqZGOgqEBCAAA)

#### How it works

```
s6ÆPSm4  Main link. Argument: n

s6       Split [1, ..., n] into chunks of length 6.
  ÆP     Test all integers for primality.
    S    Sum across columns.
         This counts the primes of the form 6k + c for c = 1, ..., 6.
     m4  Take every 4th element, leaving the counts for 6k + 1 and 6k + 5.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
1#.5 1=/6|_1 p:@i.@p:>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6zkE6Pm7/DZX1TBUMbfXNauINFQqsHDL1HAqs7Kz@a3KlJmfkK6QpmMEYFnCWJYJpaAACMJ4JmGfwHwA)

```
1#.5 1=/6|_1 p:@i.@p:>:   input: y
          _1       p:     number of primes
                     >:   less than y + 1
             p:@i.        prime range from 0 to that number
        6|                get residues modulo 6
   5 1=/                  table of values equal to 5 or 1
1#.                       sum of each (antibase 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
$`1¶
G`1111
A`^(11+)\1+$
1{6}

*M`111
\b1\b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkEslwfDQNi73BEMg4HJMiNMwNNTWjDHUVuEyrDar5eLS8gVJccUkGcYk/f9vaGIJAA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1
$`1¶
```

Count from 1 up to `n`.

```
G`1111
```

Delete numbers less than 4.

```
A`^(11+)\1+$
```

Delete composite numbers.

```
1{6}
```

Take the remainder modulo 6.

```
*M`111
```

Print the number of numbers with a remainder between 3 and 5.

```
\b1\b
```

Print the number of numbers with a remainder of 1.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>61</s> 60 bytes

### (52 bytes + 8 for the `-rprimes` flag)

```rb
->n{[1,5].map{|x|(4..n).count{|i|i.prime?&&i%6==x}}}
```

Returns an array of the form [plus primes, minus primes].

Saved 1 byte thanks to G B!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOtpQxzRWLzexoLqmokbDRE8vT1MvOb80r6S6JrMmU6@gKDM31V5NLVPVzNa2ora29n@BQlq0WSwXiDKHUBZQrqGBAZRhYglhWMKkTI1MjeCKDGDqTAwgnP//8gtKMvPziv/rFoEtBAA)

Comment: I was inspired by your answer and updated mine (in Haskell)!

Comment: @jferard I'm very glad to hear that! :)

Comment: You can use `count` on the range without the splat operator (save 1 byte).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 42 bytes

*Saved 1 byte by removing a useless space...*

*Saved 2 bytes by reorganizing the* `map` *call — thanks to @Joshua.*

*Saved 3 bytes because* `.round` *equals* `.round: 1`.

*Actually the complex exponential is cool but very expensive characterwise. Saved 10 bytes just by ditching it...*

```perl6
{[+] map {.is-prime*($_%6-1??i!!1)},5..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/Olo7ViE3sUChWi@zWLegKDM3VUtDJV7VTNfQ3j5TUdFQs1bHVE9PJb72vzWXhpmOgrmOggWQsgQRpkamRpp6QN1WCtUqaUBtmnrFiZW11v8B)

This was the version with the complex exponential. (I like it too much to delete it.) The new version works exactly in the same way, just the complex exponential is replaced by the much shorter ternary operator.

```perl6
{[+] map {.is-prime*exp(π*($_%6-1)i/8).round},5..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/Olo7ViE3sUChWi@zWLegKDM3VSu1okDjfIOWhkq8qpmuoWamvoWmXlF@aV5KrY6pnp5KfO1/ay4NMx0Fcx0FCyBlCSJMjUyNNPWABlkpVKukAbVq6hUnVtZa/wcA)

The output is a complex number `(PlusPrimes) + (MinusPrimes)i`. I hope it's not too much against the rules.

---

Explanation: It's a function that takes one integer argument. We iterate over all integers from 5 to the argument (`(5..$_)`). For each of these, we evaluate `.is-prime` (this is called on `$_`, the argument of the mapped block), multiply it (if numified, `True == 1, False == 0`) with a complex exponential that's made to be either `exp(0) = 1` (for `$_%6 = 1`) or `exp(iπ/2) = i` (for `$_%6 = 5`), and finally round it to the nearest integer. Summing them up with `[+]` gives the result.

Finally: it's really efficient, so I'm not sure if TIO won't time out before you get your output for higher numbers (for 1e5, it takes 26 sec on my machine, and TIO tends to be somewhat slower).

Comment: that's fine. good job!

Comment: I think you mean **in**efficient? Nice method though!

Comment: That was a crude attempt at irony :—).

Comment: When golfing, using the method forms of `map` or `grep` can sometimes cost you a few characters. This saves 2 chars: `{[+] map {.is-prime*exp(π*($_%6-1)i/8).round: 1},5..$_}`

Comment: Forgot to do that here, thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 21 bytes

```
u5x`p░⌠6@%1=;`╖*ƒ⌡Ml╜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9hY3R1YWxsef//dTV4YHDilpHijKA2QCUxPTtg4pWWKsaS4oyhTWzilZz//zEwMA)

Outputs the PlusPrimes first, followed by the MinusPrimes

Explanation:

```
u5x`p░⌠6@%1=;`╖*ƒ⌡Ml╜
u5x                    range(5, n+1)
   `p░                 primes in range
      ⌠6@%1=;`╖*ƒ⌡M    for each prime:
       6@%               mod 6
          1=             equal to 1
            ;`╖*ƒ        execute ╖ if p%6==1 (add 1 to register 0, consuming p)
                   l   length of resulting list (MinusPrimes)
                    ╜  push value in register 0 (PlusPrimes)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 37 bytes

```
[~>$primeYES 6%5 1,$=table tr$summap]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P7rOTqWgKDM3NdI1WMFM1VTBUEfFtiQxKSdVoaRIpbg0NzexIPa/g1UaF5eGmYK5goWZgiUQmxqZGmkqRHMpAIG6Q2aKrl20Q1qsuqJCfmkJV6wCUNN/AA)

Rather slow, tests for primality for each **K** < **N**. Works similar to my J answer.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>202</s> <s>179</s> 174 Bytes

*-23 Bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder*

*-5 Bytes thanks to Cyoce*

Function that returns an array of length 2, `[MinusPrimes, PlusPrimes]`
Execute by calling `a(n)`.

```
int[]a(int n){int[]r={0,0};for(int i=5;i<=n;i++)if(i%2*b(i)>0)if(i%6<5)r[1]++;else++r[0];return r;}int b(int n){for(int i=3;i-2<Math.Sqrt(n);i+=2)if(n%i<1)return 0;return 1;}
```

Properly formatted code on Try It Online: [Here](http://jdoodle.com/a/5UP)

Comment: Can you add a tio link?

Comment: Sorry for golfing byte-to-byte, 194 bytes: `public int[]a(int n){int[]r=new int[2];for(int i=5;i<=n;i++)if(i%2*b(i)>0)if(i%6<5)r[1]++;else++r[0];return r;}public int b(int n){for(int i=3;i<=Math.Sqrt(n)+1;i+=2)if(n%i<1)return 0;return 1;}`

Comment: 193 bytes: `public int[]a(int n){int[]r=new int[2];for(int i=5;i<=n;i++)if(i%2*b(i)>0)if(i%6<5)r[1]++;else++r[0];return r;}public int b(int n){for(int i=3;i-2<Math.Sqrt(n);i+=2)if(n%i<1)return 0;return 1;}`

Comment: lmao youre loving this arent you ;)

Comment: 179 bytes: `int[]a(int n){int[]r=new int[2];for(int i=5;i<=n;i++)if(i%2*b(i)>0)if(i%6<5)r[1]++;else++r[0];return r;}int b(int n){for(int i=3;i-2<Math.Sqrt(n);i+=2)if(n%i<1)return 0;return 1;}`, you don't need `public`. This golf is a bit better :)

Comment: You can save more 3 bytes if you use two ints instead of using an array and then returning a new array, like this: `return new[]{MinusPrimesVar,PlusPrimesVar}`

Comment: Could you swap `new int[2]` for `{0,0}`?

Comment: You can ditch the second separate method and merge it together like this: `n->{int[]r={0,0};for(int i=5,j,c;i<=n;i++){for(j=3,c=1;j-2<Math.Sqrt(i);j+=2)c=i%j<1?0:c;if(i%2*c>0)if(i%6<5)r[1]++;else++r[0];}return r;}` (**135 bytes**)

Comment: Oh, and you can golf another three bytes (**132 bytes** total) by changing `for(j=3,c=1;j-2<Math.Sqrt(i);j+=2)c=i%j<1?‌​0:c;` to `for(j=c=1;j<Math.Sqrt(i);)c=i%(j+=2)<1?‌​0:c;`

Comment: Sorry for all the comments.. Just take a look at my [Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141051/52210) to golf it by a lot more.. (thanks to *@Nevay*).

Comment: thanks for all the help, since youve posted a separate answer and stated its a golf of mine, im just gonna leave mine as is and take the lessons onto the next challenge :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Oliver*

```
õ_j ©Z%6
5â £è¥X
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V9qIKlaJTYKNeIgo+ilWA==&input=Nw==)

Outputs in the format `[PlusPrimes, MinusPrimes]`.

Comment: Hmm ... I just got back to my desk, golfed mine down to [17 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SBmagoiNTEirKPoXyU2pVg=&input=MTQ5) and then saw you'd posted this ... don't know whether I should post it or not as the crux of both our solutions is mapping over `[5,1]` to get the counts and you got there first.

Comment: @Shaggy IMO your solution has enough differences to remain a separate post. You used `f`ilter and a string; I used the mapping function of `õ` and an array. Besides, I got the `[5,1]` idea from another answer.

Comment: I'll think on it a bit; solutions in different languages using similar methods (even if one "borrowed" it from the other) is OK but 2 solutions in the same language doing so doesn't sit entirely well with me. I've edited into my post as an alternative for now.

Comment: I decided to run with it and then shaved another byte off.

Comment: You can use `5â` to get `[1,5]`

Comment: @Oliver That's really clever, thanks! Will edit in a little while.

Comment: I've completely changed my approach now; if you ant to nab my original solution to save yourself a byte, feel free :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>81</s> 69 bytes

```hs
f n=(\r->sum[1|i<-[2..n],all((>0).rem i)[2..i-1],rem i 6==r])<$>[5,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1YjpkjXrrg0N9qwJtNGN9pITy8vVicxJ0dDw85AU68oNVchUxMkmqlrGKsD5iqY2doWxWraqNhFm@oYxv7PTczMU7BVSMnn4iwoyswrUVBRSFMwQ@aYI3MsUKQsUbmmRqZG/wE)

First solution was:

```hs
r!l=sum[1|i<-l,rem i 6==r]
f n|l<-[i|i<-[2..n],all((>0).rem i)[2..i-1]]=(5!l,1!l)
```

But I read w0lf's answer in Ruby...

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB 2017a, 29 Bytes

```
sum(mod(primes(k),6)'==[5,1])
```

Explanation: `primes(k)` gets all primes up to and including k. `mod(primes(k),6)'` takes the modulus 6 of all primes and transposes it so the sum runs along the correct dimension. `==[5,1]` sets all fives (minusPrimes) to 1 in the first column and all ones (plusPrimes) to 1 in the second column. `sum()` sums each column.

This outputs `[minusPrime, plusPrime]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
/K%R6fP_TSQ5/K1
```

**[Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FK%25R6fP_TSQ5%2FK1&input=986&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%0A86%0A986%0A5252&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 16 bytes

```
m/%R6fP_TSQd,1 5
```

**[Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2F%25R6fP_TSQd%2C1+5&input=986&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%0A86%0A986%0A5252&debug=0)**

---

## How?

#### Explanation #1

```
/K%R6fP_TSQ5/K1 - Full program.

     fP_TSQ     - Filter the primes in the range [1...input].
  %R6           - Mod 6 on each.
 K              - Assign them to a variable K.
/          5    - Count the occurrences of 5 in K.
            /K1 - Count the occurrences of 1 in K.
                - Implicitly output the result.
```

#### Explanation #2

```
m/%R6fP_TSQd,1 5 - Full program.

     fP_TSQ      - Filter the primes in the range [1...input]
  %R6            - Mod 6 on each.
            ,1 5 - Push the list [1, 5]
m/         d     - Count how many of each there are.  
                 - Implicitly output the result.
```

Alternatives:

```
/K%R6fP_TSQ5/KhZ    (16 bytes)
K%R6fP_TSQ/K5/K1    (16 bytes)
m/%R6fP_TSQdj15T    (16 bytes)
m/%R6fP_TSQd[1 5    (16 bytes)   
m/%R6fP_TSQdsM`15   (17 bytes)
m/%R6.MP_ZSQd,1 5   (17 bytes)
m/%R6.MP_ZSQdj15T   (17 bytes)
m/%R6.MP_ZSQd[1 5   (17 bytes)
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12 11</s>  10 bytes

Thanks to [@cairdcoinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) for some tips in chat. Thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis?tab=profile) for saving one byte in chat.

```
ÆR%6ċÐ€1,5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5Cq2ZHuwxMeNa0x1DH9//@/hRkA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ÆR%6µ1,5=þS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5Cq2aGthjqmtof3Bf///9/CDAA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ÆR%6µċ5,ċ1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5Cq2aGtR7pNdY50G6r8///fwgwA)

---

## How does this work?

#### Explanation #1

```
ÆR%6ċÐ€1,5   As usual, full program.

ÆR           Get all the primes in the range [2...input].
  %6         Modulo each by 6.
       1,5   The two-element list [1, 5].
    ċÐ€      Count the occurrences of each of ^ in the prime range.
```

#### Explanation #2

```
ÆR%6µ1,5=þS   As usual, full program.

ÆR            Get all the primes in the range [2...input].
  %6          Modulo each by 6.
    µ         Chain separator.
     1,5      The two-element list [1, 5].
        =     Equals?   
         þ    Outer product.     
          S   Sum.
```

#### Explanation #3

```
ÆR%6µċ5,ċ1$   As usual, full program.

ÆR            All the primes in the range [2...input].
  %6          Modulo each by 6.
    µ     $   Some helpers for the chains.
       ,      Two element list.
     ċ5       The number of 5s.
        ċ1    The number of 1s.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>141</s> <s>140</s> <s>138</s> <s>106</s> <s>101</s> <s>100</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> 81 bytes

```java
n->{int r[]={0,0},c;for(;n-->4;r[n%6/4]+=c)for(c=n;c>1;c=c-1&~n%c>>-1);return r;}
```

Returns an integer-array with two values, in reversed order compared to the challenge description:
`[plusPrime, minusPrime]`.

Port of [*@Xynos*' C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140937/52210), after I golfed <s>39</s> <s>40</s> 42 bytes.
Huge help from *@Nevay* for another whopping -55 bytes.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lY9BboMwEEX3nGI2iUwBFyKStnKN1AM0mywRC8ch1bhgkDGRIsTZqQlddFksWyP/maf/R4mbiJq21OryPWHdNsaCchrtLVb0wxhx75gnK9F18ClQDx4Aaluaq5AlHOfvQ8gLkMRV0D5z2uieu50VFiUcQQOHSUfZMI@YvOBDHMZjiDwNVSjZtTGEYRC8a2Zy3Bye0yLguJX@3FBc8oSpJ@X6yHy55RFugkBlWZQwU9reaDBsnNji2fbnynn@Wt8avEDtgpOTNai/XE7hL6lP986WNW16S1vXspUmy77UNssw0VSSg@8/Vvo38LIWeF1t8bYe2e/2u7VMEs9nLZXGf7HRG6cf) (Final test case of `4000000` is exceeding the 60 sec time limit slightly.)

```java
n->{                   // Method with integer parameter and integer-array return-type
  int r[]={0,0},       //  Return integer-array, starting at [0,0]
      c;               //  Temp integer
  for(;n-->4;          //  Loop (1) as long as the input is larger than 4
                       //  and decrease `n` by 1 before every iteration
      r[n%6/4]+=c)     //    After every iteration, increase the plus or minus prime by `c`
                       //    (where `c` is either 0 or 1)
    for(c=n;           //   Reset `c` to `n`
        c>1;           //   And inner loop (2) as long as `c` is larger than 1
      c=               //    Change `c` to:
        c-1&~n%c>>-1;  //     inverting the bits of `n`,                    [~n]
                       //     modulo-`c` that result,                       [%c]
                       //     then bit-shift right that by -1,              [>>-1]
                       //     and then bitwise-AND that result with `c-1`   [c-1&]
    );                 //   End of inner loop (2)
                       //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;            //  Return result integer-array
}                      // End of method
```

Comment: 106 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},i=4,j,c;for(;i++<n;){for(j=c=1;j*j<i;)c=i%(j+=2)<1?0:c;if(i%2*c>0)r[i%6%5]++;}return r;}`

Comment: 101 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},i=4,j,c;for(;i++<n;r[i%6%5%2]-=-i%2*c>>-1)for(j=c=1;j*j<i;)c|=i%(j+=2)-1;return r;}`

Comment: 96 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},i=4,j,c;for(;i++<n;r[i%6%5%2]+=i&c)for(j=c=1;j*j++<i;)c&=-i%++j>>-1;return r;}` (-1 thanks to your `j++,++j`)

Comment: @Nevay Thanks. And been able to golf one more by changing `(j+=2)` to two separate `++`.

Comment: 94 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},i=4,j,c;for(;i++<n;r[i%6/4]+=i&c)for(j=c=1;j*j++<i;)c&=-i%++j>>-1;return r;}` (`[plusPrime, minusPrime]`).

Comment: 90 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},j,c;for(;n>4;r[n%6/4]+=n--&c)for(j=c=1;j*j++<n;)c&=-n%++j>>-1;return r;}`

Comment: 88 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},j,c;for(;n>4;r[n%6/4]+=n--&c)for(j=c=1;j*j++<n;)c&=-n%j>>-1;return r;}`

Comment: 86 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},j,c;for(;n>4;r[n%6/4]+=n--&c)for(j=c=1;++j<n;)c&=-n%j>>-1;return r;}` (will timeout for the last test case).

Comment: 84 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},j,c;for(;n>4;r[n--%6/4]+=c)for(j=c=1;++j<n;)c&=-n%j>>-1;return r;}`

Comment: 83 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},c;for(;n>4;r[n--%6/4]-=~c/2)for(c=n;c-->2;)c&=-n%c>>-1;return r;}`

Comment: 82 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},c;for(;n-->4;r[n%6/4]+=c/2)for(c=n;c-->3;)c&=~n%c>>-1;return r;}`

Comment: 81 bytes: `n->{int r[]={0,0},c;for(;n-->4;r[n%6/4]+=c)for(c=n;c>1;)c=c-1&~n%c>>-1;return r;}`

Comment: @Nevay Wow, you've been busy!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>83</s> <s>82</s> <s>80</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

Turned out a fully recursive solution was *much* shorter than mapping an array!

Output order is `[-,+]`. Craps out with an overflow error somewhere around 3490.

```
f=(n,a=[0,0])=>n>4?f(n-1,a,(g=y=>n%--y?g(y):y<2)(n)&&++a[n%6%5]):a
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(

f=(n,a=[0,0])=>n>4?f(n-1,a,(g=y=>n%--y?g(y):y<2)(n)&&++a[n%6%5]):a

)(i.value=6);oninput=_=>o.innerText=i.value>5?f(+i.value):[0,0]
```

```html
<input id=i min=6 type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [numbers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numbers/numbers.pdf), <s>66</s> <s>60</s> <s>58</s> 40 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam!* I subsequently golfed another two bytes off.

```r
cat(table(numbers::Primes(4,scan())%%6))
```

Prints `PlusPrimes MinusPrimes` to stdout; reads from stdin.

`table` tabulates the count of each occurrence of the values in its input vector, in ascending order of value. Hence, since there are only two values, namely `1` and `5` (mod 6), this is exactly the function we need, along with `numbers::Primes`, which returns all primes between `4` and the input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMkMSknVSOvNDcptajYyiqgKDM3tVjDRKc4OTFPQ1NTVdVMU/O/oYnlfwA)

## Base [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>97</s> <s>91</s> <s>89</s> <s>86</s> 65 bytes

*a bunch of bytes saved by Jarko here, too*

```r
function(n)table((5:n)[sapply(5:n,function(x)all(x%%2:x^.5))]%%6)
```

This is nearly identical to the above, except it calculates all the primes in base R rather than using a package, and it returns by function output rather than printing it out. You can see in the output that it returns a table with names `1` and `5`, with the counts below.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT7MkMSknVUPD1CpPM7o4saAgpxLE1oGrqNBMzMnRqFBVNbKqiNMz1dSMVVU10/yfpmGuyZWmYWhiqfkfAA)

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fANq80Nym1qNjKKqAoMze1WMNEJ09TVdXMzkSzJDEpJ1WjQPN/moaJARho/gcA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: (Dennis added numbers to TIO, so that works now :))

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMkMSknVSOvNDcptajYyiqgKDM3tVjDRKc4OTFPQ1NTVdXMzkRT87@JARj8BwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: `all(x%%2:x^.5>0)`, anything nonzero is already truthy, so `all(x%%2:x^.5)` works too

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam very nice! Turns out since all the values are greater than `4` we can get rid of the `>4` since we won't have `2` in there anymore as a prime, so this golfs to 40 bytes instead.

Comment: Oh, I left that in to tally the TRUE and FALSE as plus or minus, but you're right that tallying 2 and 5 works too.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 19 bytes

```
ri){mp},6f%_5e=p1e=
```

Program that takes the input from STDIN, and outputs the two numbers separated by newline through STDOUT.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyhTszq3oFbHLE013jTVtsAw1fb/f0MDEAAA)

#### Explanation

```
ri){mp},6f%_5e=p1e=

ri                        Read integer k
  )                       Add 1
       ,                  Filter the (implicit) array [0 1 ... k] ...
   {mp}                   ... on the function "is prime"
         f                Map over the resulting array...
          %               ... the function "modulus" ...
        6                 ... with extra parameter 6
           _              Duplicate the resulting array
             e=           Count occurrences ...
            5             ... of number 5
               p          Print with newline
                 e=       Count occurrences ...
                1         ... of number 1. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), <s>151</s>, <s>140</s>, 131 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].splice(5).filter(a=>!/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/.test("1".repeat(a))).reduce((r,a)=>(a%6<2?r[1]++:r[0]++,r),[0,0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYzBCoJAFEW/JSl4j7GnExUUqbRtUYuWpjDYGFM2ypspEPp3m9U9cDj3qb7KNWwGv3SDuWt@9/alx6nNJpvlJREdmdUIVkikIBxgRW7oTKNhg9SazmsGleWzpJbF/FeDlKLAmxTzhLx2HiIZEetBKw8KEQPfPyEGjhVmOajF9rAquJSVEHsu0zAxY1ymcVrh1PTW9Z2mrn/A6Xo5k/Ns7MO0I7Qg17twOP0B)

Thanks to shaggy for helping with a bug fix and golfing.

Explanation:

```javascript
n=>                                                   // Create a lambda, taking n
    [...Array(n+1).keys()]                            // Create a list from 0 to n+1
        .splice(5)                                    // remove first five elements
        .filter(a=>                                   // filter the list to get primes
             !/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/.test("1".repeat(a))) // using the famous regex here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795065/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime-with-regex 
        .reduce((r,a)=>                               // reduce the list
           (a%6<2?r[1]++:r[0]++,r),                   // by counting plus primes
           [0,0])                                     // and minus primes
```

Comment: Retturns `17,15` for 149 (Should be `18,15`). You need to increase the size of your array by 1: [TIO](https://tio.run/##DYzBasMwEAV/RQ0p7CJnY0FTaIpscu2hPfToOiCcdVDqyGalBEzbb3d1egPDvIu7u9iJn9ImTv7Ech3DN89Lb5dgq0YR0UHEzRC0QcomAqqW4jT4jmGH1PshsYCz1cP2aOr17xGM0TV@Gb3eUuKYYGVWJDyxS@AQMfPplmOQwqGtftzjs7LWql0tTdlqvZfG5HlVwukmQclfoZqyKFtcujHEcWAaxjO8fX68U0ziw9n3M/Rgnl7y@/IP). Incidentally, this is just "vanilla" ES6, nothing specific to SpiderMonkey in it. Also, you can use Stack Snippets for JS, rather than TIO. And, you have a lot of spaces you can remove.

Comment: Another couple of quick savings for you, to get you down to [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYzBCoJAFEW/JSl4j7GnExUUqbRtUYuWpjDYGFM2ypspEPp3m9U9cDj3qb7KNWwGv3SDuWt@9/alx6nNJpvlJREdmdUIVkikIBxgRW7oTKNhg9SazmsGleWzpJbF/FeDlKLAmxTzhLx2HiIZEetBKw8KEQPfPyEGjhVmOajF9rAquJSVEHsu0zAxY1ymcVrh1PTW9Z2mrn/A6Xo5k/Ns7MO0I7Qg17twOP0B).

Comment: @Shaggy I did not realise you could use reduce like that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 41 bytes

```
n->vecsum([[i>3,i<3]|i<-primes([4,n])%6])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P164sNbm4NFcjOjrTzlgn08Y4tibTRregKDM3tVgj2kQnL1ZT1SxW839iQUFOpUaegq6dAlAyrwTIVAJxlBTSNPI0NXUUos10FMx1FCyAlCWIMDUyNdJRMDQAAaB@AA)